# Смешанный вариант - Delphi/RAD XE3+

Tags: delphi

Пытаюсь переписать рабочий код - что бы не загружать файл в память.

**Оригинальный моего кода через TStringList что - работает:**

```
  begin
    If ((Edit4.Text = '') or (Edit4.Text = '0')) then
      exit
    else
      for i := 0 to t.Count - 1 do
      begin
        t[i] := iSeparatist(t[i], '-');
      end;
  end;
  t.SaveToFile('REZULTAT.txt');
  t.Free;
end;
```

А вот то что делаю я (смешанный вариант). **Не могу понять ошибку:** Просто создается пустой файл, **в чем ошибка ?**

```
  begin
    readln(f1, st);
    If ((Edit4.Text = '') or (Edit4.Text = '0')) then
      exit
    else
      for i := 0 to s.Count - 1 do
      begin
        s[i] := iSeparatist(s[i], '-'); 
      end;
  end;
  s.SaveToFile('REZULTAT.txt');
  s.Free;
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
```

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov,А как в  iSeparatist(st, '-') Знак '-' заменить на Edit1. Пробовала вот так и что то не проходит: iSeparatist(st, StrToInt(Edit1.Text), StrToInt(Edit4.Text));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Пытаюсь переписать рабочий код - что бы не загружать файл в память.

Так зачем же загружаете? Выбросите TStringList вообще

```
var
  f1: TextFile;
  f2: TextFile;
  st: string;
begin
  // Делаем проверки сразу, и если они не выполняются,
  // к файлам вообще не обращаемся
  if ((Edit4.Text = '') or (Edit4.Text = '0')) then
    Exit;

  AssignFile(f1, '1.txt');  // Входной файл
  Reset(f1);  // Открываем на чтение
  try  // закроем в секции finally
    AssignFile(f2, 'REZULTAT.txt');  // Выходной файл
    Rewrite(f2);  // Открываем на перезапись
    try  // закроем в секции finally
      while not Eof(f1) do begin  // пока не дошли до конца файла
        Readln(f1, st);  // считываем одну строку
        st := iSeparatist(st, '-');  // добавляем разделители
        Writeln(f2, st);  // записываем строку в выходной файл
      end;
    finally
      // Если при работе произошло исключение, файл гарантировано закроется
      CloseFile(f2);
    end;
  finally
    // Если при работе произошло исключение, файл гарантировано закроется
    CloseFile(f1);
  end;
end;
```

И еще пару замечаний по вашему коду. Если вы берете какой-то ресурс (открываете файл, создаете объект, блокируете обновление...), то **обязательно** освобождение ресурса должно происходить в секции **finally**

```
что-то взяли
try
  что-то сделали
finally
  освободили
end;
```

например

```
Reset(F);  // взяли ресурс
try
  // Read
finally
  CloseFile(F);  // освободили
end;
```

или

```
st := TStringList.Create;  // взяли ресурс
try
  // Read
finally
  st.Free;  // освободили
end;
```

И второе - зачем-то вы проверяете содержимое `Edit4` хотя в коде оно не используется.

Если оно используется в функции `iSeparatist`, то логичнее будет его туда передать снаружи

Comment: отличное решение. А как iSeparatist передать снаружи ? Что имеется в виду?

Comment: Зачем у вас проверка содержимого `Edit4`, если в коде он не используется?

Comment: Используется через функцию iSeparatist. Там указываю сколько символов нужно разделить.

Comment: Вот и передавайте это значение туда `iSeparatist(st, '-', StrToInt(Edit4.Text));`. А еще  лучше, вместо старой проверки поставьте `if not TryStrToInt(Edit4.Text, cnt) or (cnt <= 0) then Exit` и вызывайте `iSeparatist(st, '-', cnt);`

Comment: Спасибо Огромное. Благодаря Вам Anton Shchyrov - окончательно разобралась!

Comment: А как в  iSeparatist(st, '-') Знак '-' заменить на Edit1. Пробовала вот так и что то не проходит: iSeparatist(st, StrToInt(Edit1.Text), StrToInt(Edit4.Text));

Comment: А как объявлена функция `iSeparatist`?

Comment: Добавила функцию в основной вопрос. Посмотрите пожалуйста...

Comment: У вас функция принимает `Char`, а вы пытаетесь передать `string`. Вот `Char` и передавайте `iSeparatist(st, Edit1.Text[1])`

Answer (score 2):

В вашем втором варианте s пусто, т.к. вы его читаете не из файла, а создаёте.

```
for i := 0 to s.Count - 1 do
      begin
        s[i] := iSeparatist(s[i], '-'); 
      end;
```

Видимо вам нужно добавлять строку st в s. И читать вам небходимо до конца файла:

```
while not EOF(f1) do
  begin
    readln(f1, st);
    If ((Edit4.Text = '') or (Edit4.Text = '0')) then
      exit
    else
      s.Add(st);
  end;
```